# Android - Accessibility system permission request does not work on XIAOMI

Tags: android, accessibility, xiaomi

I'm testing accessibility feature for my android app. The idea is to request permission by redirecting the user to the accessibility screen config. After the permission is enabled by the user, the app closes the accessibility permission screen and continues to the MainActivity. Everything works fine when I test on virtual devices in device manager. But when I use my physical device Xiomi Mi 9T with android 10 (MIUI Global 12.0.7) the problems start

The code snippet below is what is used to open the accessibility permission screen

```
AppOpsManager ops = (AppOpsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent("android.settings.ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS");
startActivity(intent);
```

But it opens the screen below:

[image]

Should directly open this screen (Accessibility Menu) below:

[image]

Another problem that occurs is that, when I manually navigating to the correct accessibility option and enable the permission, the app does not identify that the permission has already been granted, does not close the screen and does not continue to the MainActivity, as it happens on the device manager devices that I tested.

Can anyone help me solve these two problems? Follow the full code below

```
public class Accessibility extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btn_permission;
    private Context context;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView((int) R.layout.activity_accessibility);
        this.context = this;
        timerStart();
        this.btn_permission = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_permission);
        getWindow().setFlags(1024, 1024);
        
        this.btn_permission.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AppOpsManager ops = (AppOpsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
                Intent intent = new Intent("android.settings.ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public void timerStart() {
        this.timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                if (isEnabled(Accessibility.this)) {
                    Accessibility.this.timer.cancel();
                    Accessibility.this.finishAndRemoveTask();
                    Context context = Accessibility.this;
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MainActivity.class));
                }
            }
        }, 0, 500);
    }

    public static boolean isEnabled(Context context) {
        StringBuilder ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE_NAME = new StringBuilder();
        ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE_NAME.append(context.getPackageName());
        ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE_NAME.append("/com.myapp.notification.NotificationService");
        String sAcessibility = ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE_NAME.toString();
        try {
            int accessibilityEnabled = Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), "accessibility_enabled");
            SimpleStringSplitter mStringColonSplitter = new SimpleStringSplitter(':');
            if (accessibilityEnabled == 1) {
                String settingValue = Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), "enabled_accessibility_services");
                if (settingValue != null) {
                    SimpleStringSplitter splitter = mStringColonSplitter;
                    splitter.setString(settingValue);
                    while (splitter.hasNext()) {
                        if (splitter.next().equalsIgnoreCase(sAcessibility)) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        } catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```